# How to run powershell command with parameter name is variable

Tags: powershell, syntax

I need to run the same command `Get-QadUser` and `Set-QadUser` to one property and his value but my property is a variable.

my code (Set doesn't work !) :

```
$property = 'MobilePhone' # OK
$value = ($User | get-QadUser -IncludedProperties $property).$property # OK
$user | Set-QadUser -$PropertyName $NewValue # NOK
```

Comment: `$Splatting = @{$property = $NewValue}; Set-QadUser @Splatting`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use PowerShell feature called **Splatting** in this case as explained by Don Jones himself here: [Windows PowerShell: Splatting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg675931.aspx).

In this you can define the parameters as a dictionary object of Property and Value pairs as below:

```
$parameters = @{$FirstPropertyName = $FirstValue; $SecondPropertyName = $SecondValue; $ThirdPropertyName = $ThirdValue}
```

Then you can pass this to your cmdlet using `@` operator as shown below:

```
Set-QadUser @parameters
```

Your complete working script will look as below:

```
$property = 'MobilePhone' # OK
$value = ($User | get-QadUser -IncludedProperties $property).$property # OK

$parameters = @{$PropertyName = $NewValue}
$user | Set-QadUser @parameters # OK
```

**Edit:** I failed to notice earlier that PetSerAl already gave the answer in comments. I hope this answer also adds value overall.